# MD5 Script Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I’m trying to utilize an MD5 script in my emails in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I need to use it in effort to turn an email address into UTF-8 code for a link parameter.

I’ve tested this code:

```
%%=MD5("example@hotmail.com")=%%
```

And the system returns the right UTF-8 value:

```
39462b91648b545e7eaf8e5640dccab5
```

However, when I replace the hardcoded email with the email merge field:

```
%%=MD5("%%emailaddr%%")=%%
```

I get an unprocessed value:

```
%%=MD5("example@hotmail.com")=%%
```

I think the issue stems from the double percentage signs calling the email address (i.e. `%%emailaddr%%`).

I have tried to right a VAR statement to get around this:

```
<!-- %%[
VAR @md5A, @md5B, @md5C
     SET @md5A = '%%=MD5("'
     SET @md5B = ''
     SET @md5C = '")=%%'
]%% -->
%%=TreatAsContent(@md5A)=%%%%=TreatAsContent(@md5B)=%%%%=TreatAsContent(@md5C)=%%
```

However, this did not work. Can you please help me out or point me in the right direction so that I may fix/solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap personalization strings with `%%` inside an AMPScript block.

```
%%[

var @email, @hashedEmail 
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
/* set @email = emailaddr */ /* you can also reference it this way */
set @hashedEmail = md5(@email)

]%%
<br>@email: %%=v(@email)=%%
<br>@hashedEmail: %%=v(@hashedEmail)=%%
```